# docker private registry push not working

Tags: docker, registry, private

I have created an private registry on server with fqdn "t-portus.at" (local ip 192.168.100.10) and can pull but don't push images.
I use Portus as authentification (on the same 192.168.100.10 machine) system between docker client and docker registry.

On the t-portus.at machine I have pushed to the repository following image
*cci/sles12sp3:latest*  (cci is the namespace where the user admin has access to pull images)

on another server with the docker client:

```
    docker login https://t-portus.at -> with user admin WORKS
    docker pull t-portus.at/cci/sles12sp3
    Using default tag: latest
    Pulling repository t-portus.at/cci/sles12sp3
    Error: image cci/sles12sp3:latest not found
```

On the t-portus.at machine the docker pull/push t-portus.at/cci/sles12sp3 works fine.

docker server version: 17.04.0-ce (on t-poruts.at and on the other server)

what's wrong?!?

Comment: Can you ping t-portus.at from your remote machine + telnet the host + port to check if it's all accessible?

Comment: telnet on port 443 works fine and ping too. Also the docker login works

Comment: the strange thing is that it's renaming your t-portus.at to t-portus without .at when docker tries to pull

Comment: sorry that was my mistake because i copied the error message manually and don't paste it automatically.